# Web application which uses jsp connection pooling hags

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc, datasource, connection-pooling

I have a jsp+servlets web application which uses a MySQL database. When I deploy my app in VPS server it hangs suddenly. I checked in error log. Nothing found in error log. Please help. I have a DBConnection class which creates a datasource and in each servlet, I use this datasource and use datasource.getConnection(); to get connection from pool, and in finally block I close the connection. All my servlets are implemented like this.

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiResourceLocking="true" path="/Admin">    
     <Resource 
         name="dbconn" 
         auth="Container" 
         type="javax.sql.DataSource"
         maxActive="150" 
         maxIdle="30" 
         maxWait="10000"
         defaultAutoCommit="false"
         removeAbandoned="true" 
         removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
         logAbandoned="true"
         username="root" 
         password="" 
         driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
         url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/lms_data?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"/>
</Context>
```

DBConnection.java

```
public class DBConnection {

    public static DataSource datasource = null;

    public static DataSource getDataSource() {
        return datasource;
    }

    static {
        initializeDataSource();
    }

    public static void initializeDataSource() {
        try {
            InitialContext initialContext;
            initialContext = new InitialContext();
            Context context = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
            datasource = (DataSource) context.lookup("dbconn");
        } catch (NamingException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(DBConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Example servlet- To show how I use connection pooling

```
import Utils.DBConnection;
import Utils.IST;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class Category extends HttpServlet {

    Connection connection = null;
    Statement statement = null;
    IST ist;
    PrintWriter out;

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        out = response.getWriter();
    }

    public void connectToServer() throws SQLException, NamingException {
        connection = DBConnection.getDataSource().getConnection();
        statement = connection.createStatement();
        ist = new IST();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        try {
            connectToServer();
            switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
                case "checkAvailability": {
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String sql = "Select category_name from course_category where category_name='" + category_name + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        out.print("exist");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "checkAvailability1": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String sql = "Select category_name from course_category where category_name='" + category_name + "' and category_id!='" + category_id + "'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        out.print("exist");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "checkwarning": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String warning = "";
                    String sql_query = "select * from course where category_id='" + category_id + "' and status='Active'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val = statement.executeQuery(sql_query);
                    if (resultset_val.next()) {
                        warning = "yes";
                    }
                    String sql_query1 = "select * from assessment where category_id='" + category_id + "' and status='Active'";
                    ResultSet resultset_val1 = statement.executeQuery(sql_query1);
                    if (resultset_val1.next()) {
                        warning = "yes";
                    }
                    if (warning.equals("yes")) {
                        throw new Exception();
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case "active_inactive": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String status = request.getParameter("status");
                    String sql = "Update course_category set status='" + status + "',last_updated_user='" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "',last_updated_ts='" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "' where category_id='" + category_id + "'";
                    int i = statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    if (i > 0) {
                    }
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            try {
                response.setStatus(400);
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                if (!statement.isClosed()) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
                statement=null;
                connection = null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
        try {
            connectToServer();
            switch (request.getParameter("mode")) {
                case "add": {
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String category_desc = request.getParameter("category_desc");
                    String status = request.getParameter("status");
                    String sql = "INSERT INTO course_category(category_name,category_desc,status,created_user,created_ts,last_updated_user,last_updated_ts) VALUES ('" + category_name + "',  '" + category_desc + "','" + status + "','" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "','" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "','" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "')";
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                case "edit": {
                    String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
                    String category_name = request.getParameter("category_name");
                    String category_desc = request.getParameter("category_desc");
                    String sql = "update course_category set category_name='" + category_name + "',category_desc='" + category_desc + "',last_updated_user='" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("log_user_id") + "',last_updated_ts='" + ist.getLastUpdatedts() + "' where category_id='" + category_id + "'";
                    statement.executeUpdate(sql);
                    connection.commit();
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            try {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                if (ex instanceof SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException) {
                    response.setStatus(1);
                } else {
                    response.setStatus(2);
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex1) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex1);
            }
        } finally {
            try {
                out.flush();
                out.close();
                if (!statement.isClosed()) {
                    statement.close();
                }
                if (!connection.isClosed()) {
                    connection.close();
                }
                statement=null;
                connection = null;
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Category.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }
}
```

Comment: Servlets are used concurrently, you should **not** put the connection and statement in a field as that will result in the connection and statement being shared by concurrent requests. That is asking for concurrency issues (especially as you'll be overwriting and closing that shared connection and statement, resulting in all kinds of race conditions). Keep the scope of the connection and statement local to the method (or at least to the lifetime of the request), and make sure to close them at the end of a request (tip: use try-with-resources)

Comment: Also check if the MySQL database on your VPS is running on localhost port 3306. Maybe it is running on a different host or on a different port.